# how to send message from group owner to multiple clients using WiFi-Direct?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

chatManagerclass

```js
public class ChatManager implements Runnable {

    private static final String TAG = "ChatHandler";

    private Socket socket = null;
    private final Handler handler;
    @Getter @Setter private boolean disable = false; //attribute to stop or start chatmanager
    private InputStream iStream;
    private OutputStream oStream;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class
     * @param socket Represents the { java.net.Socket} required in order to communicate
     * @param handler Represents the Handler required in order to communicate
     */
    public ChatManager(@NonNull Socket socket, @NonNull Handler handler) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    /**
     * Method to execute the {socketmanagers.ChatManager}'s Thread
     * To stop the execution, please use ".setDisable(true);".
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG,"ChatManager started");
        try {
            iStream = socket.getInputStream();
            oStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            //this method's call is used to call handleMessage's case Configuration.FIRSTMESSAGEXCHANGE in the MainActivity.
            handler.obtainMessage(Configuration.FIRSTMESSAGEXCHANGE, this).sendToTarget();

            while (!disable) { //...if enabled
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    if(iStream!=null) {
                        bytes = iStream.read(buffer);
                        if (bytes == -1) {
                            break;
                        }

                        //this method's call is used to call handleMessage's case Configuration.MESSAGE_READ in the MainActivity.
                        handler.obtainMessage(Configuration.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Exception : " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                iStream.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Exception during close socket or isStream",  e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to write a byte array (that can be a message) on the output stream.
     * @param buffer byte[] array that represents data to write. For example, a String converted in byte[] with ".getBytes();"
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            oStream.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

}
```

```js
public class ClientSocketHandler extends Thread {

    private static final String TAG = "ClientSocketHandler";

    private final Handler handler;
    private final InetAddress mAddress; //this is the ip address, NOT THE MACADDRESS!!!
    private Socket socket;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class.
     * @param handler Represents the handler required in order to communicate
     * @param groupOwnerAddress Represents the ip address of the group owner of this client/peer
     */
    public ClientSocketHandler(@NonNull Handler handler, @NonNull InetAddress groupOwnerAddress) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.mAddress = groupOwnerAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Method to start the socketmanagers.ChatManager}
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ChatManager chat;
        socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.bind(null);
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mAddress.getHostAddress(),
                    Configuration.GROUPOWNER_PORT), Configuration.CLIENT_PORT);
            Log.d(TAG, "Launching the I/O handler");
            chat = new ChatManager(socket, handler);
            new Thread(chat).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"IOException throwed by socket", e);
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.e(TAG,"IOException during close Socket" , e1);
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Method to close the client/peer socket and kill this entire thread.
     */
    public void closeSocketAndKillThisThread() {
        if(socket!=null && !socket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"IOException during close Socket" , e);
            }
        }

        //to interrupt this thread, without the threadpoolexecutor
        if(!this.isInterrupted()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Stopping ClientSocketHandler");
            this.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the group owner code that works for chatting with multiple devices at the same time what I want is how to send the same message to all connected users at the same time I've been searching a lot but haven't found any specific explanation for this logic how can I do that

```
public class GroupOwnerSocketHandler extends Thread {

    private static final String TAG = "GroupOwnerSocketHandler";

    private ServerSocket socket = null;
    private Handler handler;
    @Getter InetAddress ipAddress;

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     * @param handler Represents the Handler required in order to communicate
     * @throws IOException Exception throwed by {@link ServerSocket} (SERVERPORT).
     */
    public GroupOwnerSocketHandler(@NonNull Handler handler) throws IOException {
        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket(Configuration.GROUPOWNER_PORT);
            this.handler = handler;
            Log.d("GroupOwnerSocketHandler", "Socket Started");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException during open ServerSockets with port 4545", e);
            pool.shutdownNow();
            throw e;
        }

    }

    /**
     * A ThreadPool for client sockets.
     */
    private final ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            Configuration.THREAD_COUNT, Configuration.THREAD_COUNT,
            Configuration.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());


    /**
     * Method to close the group owner sockets and kill this entire thread.
     */
    public void closeSocketAndKillThisThread() {
        if(socket!=null && !socket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException during close Socket", e);
            }
            pool.shutdown();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to start the GroupOwnerSocketHandler.
     * Attention you can't stop this method, because there is a while(true) inside.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                // A blocking operation. Initiate a ChatManager instance when
                // there is a new connection
                if(socket!=null && !socket.isClosed()) {
                    Socket clientSocket = socket.accept(); //because now i'm connected with the client/peer device
                    pool.execute(new ChatManager(clientSocket, handler));
                    ipAddress = clientSocket.getInetAddress();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Launching the I/O handler");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //if there is an exception, after closing socket and pool, the execution stops with a "break".
                try {
                    if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {
                        socket.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "IOException during close Socket", ioe);
                }
                pool.shutdownNow();
                break; //stop the while(true).
            }
        }
    }

    public InetAddress getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: `group owner code that works for chatting with multiple devices at the same time `. It is unclear what that code does as you did not tell. Who can chat with who?

Comment: The group owner who's the server can chat with multiple devices at the same time but with one chat each what i want is to send a broadcast messages from a device and receive it on all connected devices i should create an array and add get the device but I don't know how to implement the code

Comment: Indeed the server has to create an array list and put the client socket of the accept() statement in it directly after that accept() statement. If the server wants to send all a message the server can use the sockets from the list. You could instead of a socket list use a ChatManager list.

Comment: Can u tell me hoe to do it exactly i really don't know how I've searched alot on Google and there's nothing

Comment: I will add my chat manager and client handle to the question